# Pandas create new columns base on all existing columns' values, except the first column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id  day1    day2    day3    day4    day5                                                                                        
1   24      0       0       0       0
2   35      0       0       0       0
3   9       0       0       0       0
4   20      0       0       0       0
5   4       0       0       0       0
6   3       0       0       1       0
7   3       0       0       0       0
8   8       0       2       0       0
```

I select a subset where values in all columns are zero, except the first column:

```
df[pd.np.where(df[['day2', 'day3', 'day4', 'day5']].eq(0).all(1), True, False)]
```

(Side Question: Is there an easier way instead of typing all columns' names?)

I wish to create a new column and assign `0` if the above condition is `True`, else `-1`.

So I tried:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(pd.np.where(df[['day2', 'day3', 'day4', 'day5']].eq(0).all(1), 0, -1), axis=1)
```

But got the error:

```
TypeError: ("'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 1')
```

I am expecting to receive this dataframe as a result:

```
id  day1    day2    day3    day4    day5    new                                                                                       
1   24      0       0       0       0       0
2   35      0       0       0       0       0
3   9       0       0       0       0       0
4   20      0       0       0       0       0
5   4       0       0       0       0       0
6   3       0       0       1       0       -1
7   3       0       0       0       0       0
8   8       0       2       0       0       -1
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: -int(not all(x[2:5] == 0)),axis=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

considering `id` is the index,

```
 df['new']=np.where(df.iloc[:,1:].eq(0).all(1),0,-1)
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that `id` is the index. Thanks.